# Get checkout information

Tags: checkout, ce-1.8.1.0

After the customer has filled in the forms in the checkout, and after they're validated, I need to display a summary of the information with the possibility to edit the information. Is here a standard module for?

If not, which methods can I use to retrieve the data?

Comment: Magento default  checkout sider bar show all data on checkout siderbar.. Checkout sider basically show on  left/right panel at checkout page

Answer (score 2):

In default magento checkout `onepage the sidebar is generally show the summary of checkout on left/right of page`.

If you want to show then you need call this side on checkout page

Which is `depends on current layout of checkout onepage(2columns-left,2columns-right,3-columns)`.

And `opcheckout.js` are update the `summary of checkout` using `checkout_onepage_progress`

**You can check this code at checkout.xml in your layout folder.**

```
  <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
.......
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
     ........
    </checkout_onepage_index>



    <checkout_onepage_progress>
.......

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>
```

In Rwd theme it coming on right panel.